# I can't get access to NTFS partition : This location could not be displayed

Tags: 14.04, partitioning

I have a problem to open the NTFS partition, this problem appeared recently, I need help please.

[image]

Answer (score -1, accepted):

fix ntfs partition with this commandline app

```
sudo apt-get install ntfs-3g
```

and use it like this

```
ntfsfix /dev/hda6
```

its gonna fix problem

**edit**

for find you partition path use `disk` app like this

[partition path](https://i.stack.imgur.com/l3V9V.png)

Comment: Thanks for your answer , I got this : Failed to determine whether /dev/hda6 is mounted: No such file or directory
Mounting volume... Failed to access '/dev/hda6': No such file or directory
Error opening '/dev/hda6': No such file or directory
FAILED
Attempting to correct errors... Failed to access '/dev/hda6': No such file or directory
Error opening '/dev/hda6': No such file or directory
FAILED
Failed to startup volume: No such file or directory
Failed to access '/dev/hda6': No such file or directory
Error opening '/dev/hda6': No such file or directory
Volume is corrupt. You should run chkdsk.

Comment: /dev/hda6 is just example and you dont have such partition on your computer replace this  `/dev/hda6` with you ntfs partition

Comment: `ntfsfix` is mis-named. It doesn't actually fix anything itself; it just marks the filesystem as needing attention so that *Windows* fixes it the next time Windows is booted. The filesystem can be flagged for fixing entirely within Windows, too.

Comment: @RodSmith its mark fileSystem or what ever, problem get solve ? Seem s **YES**

Comment: The problem will be fixed *only after rebooting into Windows.* That's a *necessary* part of the repair that your answer did not mention. Running `ntfsfix` is *not* a necessary part of the repair, since you can as easily run `CHKDSK` on the disk from within Windows. Furthermore, this problem can often be caused by a failure to [disable Hibernation](http://www.tenforums.com/tutorials/2859-hibernate-enable-disable-windows-10-a.html) or [Fast Startup](http://www.tenforums.com/tutorials/4189-fast-startup-turn-off-windows-10-a.html) within Windows.